# CodeIgniter 2: not loading MY_Loader class

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have been trying to override the "database" method of the loader class (CI_Loader). I followed the instructions found on the CodeIgniter user guide: [Creating Libraries](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html) (scroll to "Extending Native Libraries"). But MY_Loader class does not load automatically and is not used in `$this->load` calls in place of the CI core Loader class.
I've only created MY_Loader class (application/libraries/MY_Loader.php as specified in the user guide). Is there something I'm missing?
I've tried to put it in config/autoload.php for the libraries section of that file, and it indeed is autoloaded, but then I access to the library using `$this->my_loader->database()` and that's not the idea...

I paste below the content of application/libraries/MY_Loader.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader {

    function database($params = '', $return = FALSE, $active_record = NULL)
    {
        echo '---test---';
        exit;
    }
}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The loader class is part of the core so it needs to go in "application/core/MY_Loader.php"

Any class you wish to extend should go in the corresponding directory in your applications folder.  You should be able to take the class you wrote, drop it in there, and presto...it should work.  No hacking required.

Comment: thank you, worked like a charm! The user guide is not clear on the path for the case of core classes and I also didn't realized that, but it is very logical. Thanks.

Comment: do i need to prefix my classes with "MY_" @GarciaWebDev

Comment: @ahmad05 yes you do. If you want to change the prefix (not sure why you would) you can change the 'subclass_prefix' value in application/config/config.php to whatever takes your fancy

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've managed to get it working, but I'm not sure if it's the best or  most elegant way.
First, I added "my_loader" to application/config/autoload.php on the libraries section.
Then I checked what `$this->load` was inside a controller and it was CI_Loader instance, so in MY_Loader class' constructor I made a CI reference and replaced it's load property with a reference to MY_Loader: `$CI->load = $this;`.

The final MY_Loader class is this:

```
class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load = $this;
    }

    function database($params = '', $return = FALSE, $active_record = NULL)
    {
        parent::database($params, $return, $active_record);

        // bootstrap doctrine
        require_once APPPATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'hooks' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'doctrine' . EXT;
        bootstrap_doctrine();
    }
}
```

Please, if you come with a better/smarter solution, post an answer. Thanks.

Comment: The better solution is the correct solution posted by Michael Copeland. Any extensions to the core will be handled by the CI engine if you put the file in the application/core folder and prefix it with the value specified by the 'subclass_prefix' value in config.php